# Nexus Camera ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE with MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-video-record

Within our application, we give the user's the option to take a new video with the `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` or get a video currently stored in their phone with the `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent. Within Nexus devices using the default Google Camera App we are having some trouble accessing new videos taken with the `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent.

If we just call

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, Globals.UPLOAD_VIDEO_NEW);
```

Within `onActivityResult`, the `URI` from `data.getData()` doesn't point to the correct location. The video does get saved onto the device with this method, so the user could always try to upload it again. But we don't want to have the user go through those extra steps.

This next method I use for all devices, I have a class `mCurrentMediaUri` which I create and pass as `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra for the intent.

```
mCurrentMediaUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(UpdateProfileActivity.this, 
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", videoFile);

takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCurrentMediaUri);

if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, Globals.UPLOAD_VIDEO_NEW);
}
```

However using this method with the Nexus devices using the Google Camera App, the video doesn't get stored not only at the given `URI`, but doesn't get stored on locally on the device anywhere.

If the user downloads another camera app from the Play Store, we don't have this issue. Is there a way we can find where the video is getting stored if we don't pass the `URI` to the intent with the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`? I did find this post [Camera app of Nexus 6P does not write video file to MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37101151#comment1) , but it states

"The videos can be found at /data/data/com.commonsware.android.videorecord/files/videos"

And from my understanding we can't access that directory. Have someone come across this issue before, and if so how can it be solved?